# Ошибка с num_rows "Trying to get property of non-object in"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Проверяю кол-во записей в запросе.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM city WHERE name = $cc_city and users_id = $users_id_db";
$result = $db_conn -> query($sql);
if($result -> num_rows > 0)
{

  $message = "Данные есть";
}

else
{
  $message = "Данных нет";

}
```

Появляется ошибка **Trying to get property of non-object in** 
Ругается на строку `if($result -> num_rows > 0)`

Подскажите в чем дело?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос закрыт. Проблема была в запросе

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM city WHERE name = $cc_city and users_id = $users_id_db";
```

т.к. имя города $cc_city - это текстовое значение, то в условии нужно было поставить значение в ковычки. Исправил запрос на

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM city WHERE name = '$cc_city' and users_id = '$users_id_db'";
```

И всё заработало